# (Python) List index out of range - iteration

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, out

```
for i in range(len(lst)):    
   if lst[i][0]==1 or lst[i][1]==1:
        lst.remove(lst[i])
return lst
```

This gives "IndexError: list index out of range" Why is this happening?

Comment: What is `lst` ? copy the whole function please.

Comment: If you have five dollars and someone asks you to count them out one by one, but then they steal one while you're doing it, you won't count to five, will you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're modifying the list you're iterating over. If you do that, the size of the list shrinks,  so eventually `lst[i]` will point beyond the list's boundaries.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> lst[2]
3
>>> lst.remove(1)
>>> lst[1]
3
>>> lst[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It's safer to construct a new list:

```
return [item for item in lst if item[0]!=1 and item[1]!=1]
```

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't `remove` items from the `list` as you iterate over it; that changes the indices of all subsequent items, hence the `IndexError`. You could try a simple list comprehension:

```
lst = [item for item in lst if (item[0] != 1 and item[1] != 1)]
```

Comment: Or if the objective is to modify the list in place, then `lst[:] =`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it means that you are providing an index for which a list element does not exist.

E.g, if your list was [12, 32, 50, 71], and you asked for the element at index 10, you would be well out of bounds and receive an error, as only elements 0 through 3 exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you remove items in the list which reduces its size. What you have to do is make an array with the indexes you want to remove and remove them backwards.

Another way would be to create a temporary list that you would add the elements you don't want to delete and then overwrite your initial list with the list containing all the elements you want to keep.

Answer (score -1):

By process of deduction I have concluded that your lst looks something like this:

lst = [ ...[val1, val2], [val1, val2], [val1, val2]... ]

I think what happened here is you confused your 'for i in range', with a 'for i in' (I have done this many times also.)

The line where your error is occurring is:
    lst.remove(lst[i])

You can correct this by simply changing your code like so:

```
for i in lst:  
    if i[0] ==1 or i[1] ==1:  
        lst.remove(lst[i])
return lst
```

The way your code was structured before list[i] didn't make any sense, your i was a number greater than the number of two-value-items in lst.

=D