# Python: index out of range but I can't see why

Tags: indexing

I'm trying to code a program that opens a file, creates a list that contains each line of this file, and removes some words from this list. I have an Index Out of Range error.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

# open the file
f = open("test.txt", "r")
# a list that contains each line of my file (without \n)
lines = f.read().splitlines()
# close the file
f.close()

# some words I want to delete from the file
data = ["fire", "water"]

# for each line of the file...
for i in range(len(lines)):
    # if this line is in [data]
    if lines[i] in data:
        # delete this line from [data]
        print(lines[i])
        del lines[i]
```

This is my text file:

```
sun
moon
*
fire
water
*
metal
```

This is my output:

```
fire
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 16, in <module>
    if lines[i] in data:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Python) List index out of range - iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819504/python-list-index-out-of-range-iteration)

Comment: I changed my code and it does not work for "water". why ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll address the out of index error first.
What's happening, in your first post, is that it takes the length of the list
which is 7, so len(lines) = 7 which will result in range(7) = (0,7) which will do this:

- lines[0] = sun
- lines[1] = moon
- lines[2] = *
- lines[3] = fire
- lines[4] = water
- lines[5] = *
- lines[6] = metal

=>

- lines[0] = sun
- lines[1] = moon
- lines[2] = *
- *deleted* lines[3] = fire
- lines[3] = water
- lines[4] = *
- lines[5] = metal

If you now delete lines[3] it will still try to iterate over lines[6] although it won't exist anymore.

It will also continue to iterate over the next index lines[4] so water will never be checked, it is absorbed.

I hope this helps and I suggest you do this instead:

```
# open the file
f = open("test.txt", "r")
# a list that contains each line of my file (without \n)
lines = f.read().splitlines()
# close the file
f.close()

# some words I want to delete from the file
data = ["fire", "water"]


for i in data:
    if i in lines:
        lines.remove(i)

print(lines)
```

Output:
['sun', 'moon', '*', '*', 'metal']

Comment: Don't forget to adjust the solution for multiple occurances!

Comment: In summary: Don't delete list elements, while iterating over the list. And what @Wonneju said: You only delete the first occurence of each `data` item in `lines`.